# How to change the font Size of the webpage in Firemonkey mobile application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing mobile application for iOs and Android. And I have created mobile application which has the TwebBrowser component and in this I have loaded the webpage and inside this I have code that is mentioned below:

```
<head>
<style>  
body 
@font-face {
font-family: MyFont;
src: url('BOOKOS.ttf')
}
                  div {  
                  background: transparent;  
                  color: #f2e9e3;  
                  text-align:justify;
                  font-family:MyFont;
                  font-size:17;
                  }  
                  div.padded {  
                  padding-top: 10px;  
                  padding-right: 10px;  
                  padding-bottom: 0.25in;  
                  padding-left: 10px;  
                  }  
                  a:link {
                  COLOR: #f2e9e3;
                  }
                  a:visited {
                  COLOR: #f2e9e3;
                  }
                  a:hover {
                  COLOR: #f2e9e3;
                  }
                  a:active {
                  COLOR: #f2e9e3;
                  }
                  </style>  
                  </head>
```

Currently the webpage font is set inside the webpage. And we have the configuration settings where the user can specify the font size. So, how can I able to change the font size of the webpage?

Comment: Is that in a style tag? Please post a little more of the HTML (including the corresponding tag). And why is this tagged with two different versions of Delphi?

Comment: You really need to tell us if you are creating *presenting* the HTML or loading it from external sources. One will simply be setting the CSS the other overriding the browser component's zoom function?